How thread works with the 'start routine' function passed at the time of `pthread_create`?
I am just starting on how threading really works on linux (Ubuntu) using pthreads library. And I am stuck on first program. See the code first :
#include <pthread.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void* th_func(void* arg) {
    cout << "Indside Thread Start Routine !!\n";
    return NULL;
}

void foo() { cout << "Inside Foo !!\n"; }

int main(void) {
    int ret;
    foo();
    pthread_t thread;
    if (!(ret = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, th_func, NULL))) {
        cout << "ret = " << ret << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Simple compilation and test run of the program here :( I intentionally use 0,1,... before $ just for the sake of indexing and trying to explain more efficiently )
0$ g++ t0.cpp
1$ ./a.out
Inside Foo !!
ret = 0
Indside Thread Start Routine !!
2$ ./a.out
Inside Foo !!
ret = 0
Indside Thread Start Routine !!
3$ ./a.out
Inside Foo !!
ret = 0
Indside Thread Start Routine !!
Indside Thread Start Routine !!
4$ ./a.out
Inside Foo !!
ret = 0
Indside Thread Start Routine !!
5$ ./a.out
Inside Foo !!
ret = 0

I am happy with all the test run except the run indexed with 3$. First let me share my understanding on the other run.

At run 1$, 2$ and 4$, the main thread ended after the created thread ended resulting the start routine (function in this case th_func) to execute before program ends.
At run 5$ however the main thread ended before the created thread which causes created thread to terminate before code given to it processes. (th_func not printing cout statement)

Let me come to the 3$ one which grabs all my attention or probably stuck in my head. My questions are : 

Why the created thread not terminated after printing whatever on cout statement and returning NULL ? (As DESCRIPTION section point no.2 suggests from man page of pthread_create:


DESCRIPTION         top
The pthread_create() function starts a new thread in the calling
process.  The new thread starts execution by invoking
start_routine(); arg is passed as the sole argument of
start_routine().
The new thread terminates in one of the following ways:
It calls pthread_exit(3), specifying an exit status value that
is available to another thread in the same process that calls
pthread_join(3).
It returns from start_routine().  This is equivalent to
calling pthread_exit(3) with the value supplied in the return
statement.
It is canceled (see pthread_cancel(3)).
Any of the threads in the process calls exit(3), or the main
thread performs a return from main().  This causes the
termination of all threads in the process.


If it returns the why print the statement of cout (cout << "Indside Thread Start Routine !!\n";) twice ? Is thread created twice ?

I put up my head on the internet for several hours but honestly could not find answer. Perhaps my code is not thread safe or idk ? I just could think may be pthread_join help but still it just waits the created thread to be terminated and that won't help my questions ( printing twice or maybe calling th_func twice ). So I am wishing someone might help ...
Thanks in advance :)

A side note: in C++ you should use std::thread (or std::jthread) rather than pthreads.

You forgot to add pthread_join at the end of your main function.

Use std::thread, std::mutex, std::scoped_lock. They have been available since C++11 (13 years at least). There should not be much reason to use pthreads anymore.

I'm curious why you guys insist on using std::thread over pthreads?  If he is specifically targeting Linux, I don't see any advantage.  Kind of orthogonal to the problem at hand anyway...

@Jason there's no reason whatsoever to use an OS specific solution when there is an at least as good standard one (which is also a lot more C++ friendly e.g. using capturing lambdas, class methods and more). Having said that, I agree it is not directly related to the problem at hand, which is why I started my comment with "A side note: ".

@Jason People here love to provide code review in comments for some reason, despite not being asked to and comments not being the right place to do so.

Ah that makes more sense.  I know std::thread just uses pthreads under the hood on Linux, so I was just curious what they could have added to it.  I'm a dumb, grug procedural guy, so that kind thing doesn't come to mind right away.  Thanks!

@Jason Another reason is because when you use threads you also need to use locking and it is very easy to make bugs with manual locking and unlocking of mutexes. Using std::mutex/std::scoped_lock you have RAII locks which will always unlock when you exit a scope (even when you have exceptions).

@Yksisarvinen do you see any downside alerting users regarding good practices in the comments ? I was under the impression it is a positive and helpful thing to do.

@Yksisarvinen No answers are not the right place to do recommendations on how to do things differently. Comments are really that, and if the comments help people to avoid writing buggy code then I'd say there is room for that :)

@PepijnKramer Comments help page says that comments should be used to Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post (among other things). But changing pthread to std::thread would change the problem completely, so it cannot be considered "improving the post".

@Yksisarvinen you do have a point according to formal help page. However I still don't see the downside of it, and many people in the community (including a lot of very high rep and experienced contributors) do it and seem to think it is helpful.

@Yksisarvinen Say the user has a problem shooting himself in the foot. He has lots of misfires, and  once in a blue moon the projectile turns out to be a carrot! Would it be prudent to note that shooting yourself in the foot might not be the brightest idea ever?

@all, well i have  much to say but for now none of these are direct answer to my question. Thanks:)

@kzsnyk,  as pthread_join says : The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by        thread to terminate. But as I ask in my question it is not about waiting the thread to terminate. It should have terminated once it return from 'th_func()'. Instead it prints twice, that's where I can not simply satisfy myself thinking what might be the reason ? or is it UB if threads are not joined >?

@Jason, For a deep dive into why you should use std::thread instead of pthread_create see here: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6120/2019fa/blog/threads-not-as-libraries/

@MrHandsome what version is your libc: dpkg -l libc6

I'm disappointed, @SolomonSlow.  I thought that article might be an interesting read. I found it a frustrating one instead, on account of numerous subtle, but consequential errors.  I don't dispute the general thesis that having and using threading semantics specified by the language is superior to using a bolt-on threading library, but I reject all of the article's arguments for that being the only viable possibility.

@JohnBollinger FYI, that is named after and seems to copy from a well-known 2004 article but without explicitly saying so https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse590p/05au/HPL-2004-209.pdf

@JeffGarrett, Thank you for finding the original. I thought that's what I was linking to. Must pay more attention next time. IMO, the titles of both works are not literally true, and I think Boehm makes it clear in his abstract that he's talking about a compiler that was designed without taking threads into consideration, and a threading library that was designed, independently of the compiler. When you use std::thread (or, std::anythingelse) you're normally using a library that was developed along side of, and released with the compiler.

The code is fine. (*)
This is consistent with a glibc bug that can print duplicate lines on program exit: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14697
The bug is an old one, which is fixed in glibc 2.38.
(*) One should prefer the standard facilities such as std::jthread, as interactions are much more precisely specified now. And one should almost always join threads. But these are not the problem.
